# Is it possible to write mapping template in java in amazon api gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to write template mapping in a java code?
[Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-models) provided by Amazon mentions only about Velocity template for the request transformations.

However, I would like to use java code to transform request. Is possible?

Comment: Maybe you could consider using https://github.com/lambadaframework/lambadaframework which will abstract whole API Gateway headache.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. If you want a flexible way to transform request/responses you can proxy all [requests through lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) and perform the transformation in lambda function.